How do I install skirting around stairs when there's a stringer in the way?
In the hallway of our London Victorian terraced house, we recently removed all the plaster and hardwall, and are in the process of re-plastering. Halfway down the hallway are wooden steps up to a landing. I'm now wondering how I'm supposed to add skirting board up these steps when there's a wooden stringer in the way:

Even after the plaster skim has been added, this stringer will be proud from the wall. It's right in the way of the skirting board.
The same is true of the stringer that goes down the stairs from the hallway. That will also be proud from the wall, even after the plaster has been skimmed over the plasterboard.

I can only imagine that I'd need to rout out space on the back side of the skirting board to leave space for the stringer.
What's the right thing to do here?
